# org.hibernate.HibernateException error

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I'm getting this error continuously...Eclips IDE with appach tomcat

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    com.rmi.servlet.ProvinceServlet.doPost(ProvinceServlet.java:59)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Hibernate dependency to your project.

Basically, you need to add one of these jars:
http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.hibernate.HibernateException

Here is how to do it from Eclipse:
http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)